# error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing pocketsphinx

Tags: python-2.7, pocketsphinx

When trying to install the python2.7 module pocketsphinx gives the error below:

**error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1**

I'm using the linux 18.1 (Serena)

Thank u very much in advance

Comment: This only signals that GCC failed to compile some source file. There should be a log file with more output. If you're installing the package with pip, give it -vvv to get verbose output.

Comment: output https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mbbl8nixru7c40/Documento%20n%C3%A3o-salvo%201?dl=0

Comment: Looks like the pulseaudio devel package is not installed, as pulse/pulseaudio.h header file is missing. On CentOS (and I guess Fedora) the package is named pulseaudio-libs-devel.

Comment: You're right, I installed it.
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev

after
sudo pip install pocketsphinx

and worked perfectly

Thank you very much Borko!